# Convergence of $c_j = \sum_{k=1}^nx_k\cos(2\pi\frac{k-1}{n})j$

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence

S. Kim, K, Umeno, and A. Hasegawa, Corrections of the NIST Statistical Test Suite for Randomness (available at http://arxiv.org/pdf/nlin/0401040.pdf) mention page 8-9 that:

$c_j = \sum_{k=1}^nx_k\cos(2\pi\frac{k-1}{n})j$

converges to the normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $n/2$ for $x_k$ random and $x_k =\pm 1$.

What is a proof for this?

Comment: I suspect some heavy misprints. Could you check the question? (And please make it self-contained, one should not have to read an off-site document to understand the question.)